# Getting "Unexpected token 'catch' while compiling ejs"

Tags: node.js, ejs

index.ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>student manangement System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="https:// use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#">Back</a>
    <h1> Student manangement System</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="search"placeholder="search"id="search">
    <a href="/add"><input type="button"Value="Add"id="btn"></a>
    </form>
    <div class="table"> 
    <form action="/"method="POST">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="id">ID</th>
                <th class="fname">First Name</th>
                <th class="lname">Last name</th>
                <th class="loc">Location</th>
                <th class="mail">Email</th>
                <th class="birth">DOB</th>
                <th class="edu">Education</th>
                <th class="update">Action</th>
                <th class="del">Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++){ %>
            <tr>               
                <td><%= i+1%></td>
                <td><%= users[i].Firstname %></td>
                <td><%= users[i].Lastname %></td>
                <td><%= users[i].Location %></td>
                <td><%= users[i].Email %></td>
                <td><%= users[i].Dob %></td>
                <td><%= users[i].Education %></td>
                <td class="update"><a href="edit.html">Edit</a></td>
                <td class="del"><a href="#"id="del">Delete</a></td>    
           </tr>
           } %>
            </table>
        </div>
            </form> 
            
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'catch' in C:\Users\Nirmal\Desktop\final\views\index.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Template.compile (C:\Users\Nirmal\Desktop\final\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:673:12)
    at Object.compile (C:\Users\Nirmal\Desktop\final\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:398:16)
    at handleCache (C:\Users\Nirmal\Desktop\final\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:235:18)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\Nirmal\Desktop\final\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:274:16)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\Nirmal\Desktop\final\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\Nirmal\Desktop\final\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\Nirmal\Desktop\final\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\Nirmal\Desktop\final\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Nirmal\Desktop\final\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the problem but you are missing a `</tbody>` closing tag, the `</div>` is closing before the `form` even though you opened it before.

Comment: And the error itself doesn't look like from that file as it mentions `catch` token, maybe it is trying to compile one of the scripts included and failing, try removing the `<script>` tags just for test... then if no error, add one at a time...